# How to test a function that makes a call to a static function - trying to fake static function

Tags: c#, vb.net, unit-testing, moq, microsoft-fakes

Please note that I am unit testing VB.NET code using C#. I am trying to mock a interface call which has an implementation that calls a static function.  I am new to unit testing in .NET and mocking/faking in general.

I have tried to use the moq and Microsoft Fakes frameworks but cannot figure out exactly how to make this work.

Project 1 (Static) - Cannot change:

```vb
Public Class CommonCode
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function HelpFunction(objContext, objString) As Integer
        Using objCmd As SqlCommand = objContext.DbConnection.CreateCommand()
            'code - db call
            return number
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Project 2:

```vb
Public Class Validate
    Private objHelper As IHelper

    Public Function GetErrors(objContext, objString) As String
        If objHelper.GetHelp(objContext, objString) < 1
            Return "ERROR"
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

I tried adding an interface to help fake this function as I found I could not fake a static function.

```vb
Public Interface IHelper
    Public Function GetHelp(objContext, objString) As Integer
End Interface
```

```vb
Public Class Helper Implements IHelper
    Public Function GetHelp(objContext, objString) As Integer
        Return CommonCode.HelpFunction(objContext, objString)
    End Function
End Class
```

Test Case (note that most these items are used for other tests so just have that in mind)

```
[TestClass]
public class RTATAXSTATUS_01_PRC_Validation_Test
{
    ShimMainObj shimTestObj;
    MainObj testObj;
    Validate objValidation;
    Mock<IHelper> mockHelper;
    IDisposable shimContext;
    bool blnIsValid;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockHelper= new Mock<IHelper>();
        shimContext = ShimsContext.Create();
        shimTestObj= new ShimTest();
        testObj = shimTestObj.Instance;
        objValidation = new Validate ();
        blnIsValid = true;
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        shimContext.Dispose();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_StreamID_ExistsInPetrinex()
    {
        string strId = "TESTME";

        //for other validation in the GetErrors function
        shimTestObj.Value = () => { return strId); };

        mockHelper.Setup(m => m.GetHelp(null, strId)).Returns(1234);

        string strMsgs = objValidation.GetErrors(null, testObj.Value);

        Assert.IsFalse(blnIsValid, "Errors should have been found.");
        Assert.IsTrue(strMsgs.Contains("ERROR"));
    }
}
```

This ends up returning a NullReferenceException because when trying to use the objContext, it see's object as a null object. Any ideas would be appreciated, I just don't have the knowledge to proceed and could not find anything online that worked for me.

I was wondering if it is possible to have another implementation of this interface in my tests project and somehow force my GetHelp interface to point to the implementation I want to use.  I already created another implementation but am not sure how to use it in place of the original.

Note that the Shims work correctly as they are being tested in prior unit testing code, although I am sure my code is quite bad so any suggestions would be nice.

Comment: I'm no vb.net expert, but in general you test methods by substituting their collaborators (inputs, outputs, contexts, etc).  In this case, if you're trying to test `HelpFunction` you can probably substitute the database that it is operating on with a test database, and you could set up a test case in the database, then verify after the call that the database was changed in the way you expected.

Comment: @Gus Hi Gus, I am trying to test ```GetErrors``` function in the ```Validate``` Class. This function previously made a call to ```HelpFunction``` but I put a interface between the ```Validate``` class and ```CommonCode``` to allow me to fake this interaction.  I do not want to touch the database, the database call calls a function which without the proper security will not run. I am just trying to fake the returned result from the database, i.e. faking what ```HelpFunction``` or ```GetHelp``` funciton returns.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variables instance to public `Private objHelper As IHelper;`

and from the unit test I called `objValidation.objHelper = new FakeImplementationClass();`

This worked for me to bypass the call to the implementation which had called the database.